# Is it possible embed Vevo videos from vevo.com in Third party websites

Tags: html, api

I am developing video library website, and after using YouTube player, I need to use Vevo player and its database, so any one have idea how to use vevo video along with their player in website.? on their website I am unable to find anything related to API calls.

**Sample embed code for Vevo :**

```
 <iframe width="575" height="324" src="http://cache.vevo.com/m/html/embed.html?video=USIV30500018" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But, there is no information about vevo api calls and player on Vevo.com

Answer (score 0):

You have to purchase some copyrights and register your server so that all the vevo videos can play on your website. For more information refer this link. [How does Facebook play a YouTube video which has been banned from embedding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829590/how-does-facebook-play-a-youtube-video-which-has-been-banned-from-embedding)

Comment: hmm.. thanks for reply, Actually now I am searching APIs which can take videos from WWW.VEVO.COM, i.e if i need michecl jackson videos then in youtube i will use gdata URI search query and get all those videos, same way if is there any API for VEVO